# Is there a way to “break” or “continue” within a Python function?

Tags: python

I need to write a function (a Flask view) that will test several conditions about a request and return a message based on those tests.

For example…

```
def index():
    test1result = test1(request.form['data'])
    if not test1result:
        message = 'Failed test 1'

    test2result = test2(request.form['data'])
    if not test2result:
        message = 'Failed test 2'

    test3result = test3(request.form['data'])
    if not test3result:
        message = 'Failed test 3'

    return render_template('index.html', message = message)
```

If the first test fails, I don’t want the 2nd or 3rd test to run and overwrite my message. My first thought was to insert return statement into each of the IF blocks, but that seems messy.

Comment: It's not messy at all. Use `return` !

Comment: I think the best method is to take a book and study the basics

Comment: You can also use exceptions for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `elif`.

First run all tests, and then the `if-elif` block

```
def index():
    test1result = test1(request.form['data'])
    test2result = test2(request.form['data'])
    test3result = test3(request.form['data'])
    if not test1result:
        message = 'Failed test 1'
    elif not test2result:
        message = 'Failed test 2'
    elif not test3result:
        message = 'Failed test 3'

    return render_template('index.html', message = message)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should in this case either use `elif` to only branch into your later tests if the first test failed, or just `return`. But you could also do this:

```
def index():
    messages = []
    test1result = test1(request.form['data'])
    if not test1result:
        message.append('Failed test 1')

    test2result = test2(request.form['data'])
    if not test2result:
        message.append('Failed test 2')

    test3result = test3(request.form['data'])
    if not test3result:
        message.append('Failed test 3')

    return render_template('index.html', messages=messages)
```

And have your view display *all* the error messages.

Answer (score 2):

> My first thought was to insert return statement into each of the IF blocks, but that seems messy.

It isn't if you do a small refactoring:

```
def index_message():
    test1result = test1(request.form['data'])
    if not test1result:
        return 'Failed test 1'

    test2result = test2(request.form['data'])
    if not test2result:
        return 'Failed test 2'

    test3result = test3(request.form['data'])
    if not test3result:
        return 'Failed test 3'

    return '......'

def index():
    message = index_message()
    return render_template('index.html', message = message)
```

Alternatively you can use `else` and `elif` to avoid further processing.

If you have more tests, add them to a data structure (e.g.: `list`) and use a loop. Don't repeat the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop.

```
def index():
   tests = [test1, test2, test3]
   for i, test in enumerate(tests, 1):
       if not test(request.form['data']):
           return render_template('index.html', message="Failed test %s" % i)
```